# Will a parent record be updated if you update it's child object (including related fields on the parent)

Tags: dml, update

I can write a SOQL relationship query to lookup Contacts, and at the same time get some data on the related Account. This returns a list of Contacts, each of which has data on it's related parent Account.

If I update info on the related account, like contact1.Account.Name = 'NewName';
and then I update the contact will it write the updated Account fields to the DB? Or just the Contact fields?

Answer (score 1):

No, the related records will not also be updated. See this code snippet:

```
System.SavePoint initialState = Database.setSavepoint();

final String INITIALVAL = 'Initial';
Account a = new Account(Name = INITIALVAL);
insert a;
Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'person', AccountId = a.Id);
insert c;
List<Contact> lc = [SELECT LastName, Account.Name FROM Contact Where Id = :c.Id];

final String NEWVAL = 'NewValue';
lc[0].Account.Name = NEWVAL;
update lc[0];

List<Account> la = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.Id];
system.assertEquals(INITIALVAL, la[0].Name, 'Updating an object should not update it\'s attached objects');
system.assertNotEquals(NEWVAL, la[0].Name, 'Updating an object should not update it\'s attached objects');

Database.rollback(initialState);
```